# Rails артефакт при изменении расположения элементов во view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При изменении элементов во `view` появляется артефакт, помогите разобраться в чем причина?

view project#show:

```
<div class="container">

    <h3><%= @project.name %></h3>

  <h2>Tasks</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped" id="tasks_list">
    <%= render @project.tasks %>
  </table>

  <h2>Add a task:</h2>
  <%= render 'tasks/form'  %>

  <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>

</div>
```

[image: Отображение view при условии нахождения списка сверху]

Меняю местами список всех задач с формой добавления новых задач в текущем проекте и получаю следующее:

```
<div class="container">

    <h3><%= @project.name %></h3>

  <h2>Add a task:</h2>
  <%= render 'tasks/form'  %>

  <h2>Tasks</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped" id="tasks_list">
    <%= render @project.tasks %>
  </table>

  <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>

</div>
```

[image: Отображение view при условии нахождения списка под формой добавления]

Размер списка задачь проекта не изменился - но появился странный артифакт.

Answer (score 1):

**Дайте угадаю. Объект в форме создаётся так?**

```
@project.tasks.build
```

**Тогда это не артефакт.** Это пустой, новосозданный, ещё не сохранённый объект. Да, он уже лежит в этой коллекции и тоже рендерится. Самый простой способ решить эту проблему — просто исключить его из рендеринга, выбрав только сохранённые:

```
render @project.tasks.select(&:persisted?)
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, в форме было `@project.tasks.build`. Решил проблему заменой этого кода на `@project.tasks.klass.new`. Или так не стоит делать?

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko `klass`, по-моему, даже не документирован. Это то же, что и `Task.new`, но более витиевато.